# Deployed Java Spring application: cannot connect to JawsDB on Heroku

Tags: java, mysql, spring, heroku, mariadb

I am trying to deploy a Java Spring application on Heroku with MariaDB database. On Heroku I am using JawsDB as it is recommended. All connection properties are set through integrated Heroku environment variables. Build and deployment using Heroku CLI finish with success.
Connection using HeidiSQL to the same JawsDB works perfectly, so the URL parameters should be correct. The application runs and connects to the local MariaDB the same way, just without any issues. I also tried to set the database driver to "com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" and to "org.mysql.jdbc.Driver" but all of them failed.

When I deploy my application, I get this error stack:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain database connection
------------------------------------
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 
'mysql://u3r5w4ayhxzdrw87.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/{database_name}'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

This is how the Bean configuration in **AppConfiguration.java** looks like, and it works when I run the application locally:

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl(System.getenv("JDBC_URL"));
    basicDataSource.setUsername(System.getenv("JDBC_USERNAME"));
    basicDataSource.setPassword(System.getenv("JDBC_PASSWORD"));

    return basicDataSource;
}
```

I am also copying the dependencies, as configured in the **pom.xml**:

```
    (...)
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    (...)
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I copied the .jar file which contains MySQL and MariaDB connection drivers to the **WEB-INF/libs** folder: `mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar` & `mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar`.

***Does anyone have an advice or spotted something that can be useful?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql://u3r5w4ayhxzdrw87.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/` is not a valid JDBC URL and most likely the cause of your issue.

Which environment variables do you use on Heroku?

We rewrite the standard `DATABASE_URL` (as well as others, including `JAWSDB_URL` and `JAWSDB_MARIA_URL`) to a JDBC compliant URL and make it available as `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`. `JDBC_USERNAME` and `JDBC_PASSWORD` are available as well. Try using those and see if this solves your issue.

Comment: You are correct. The JDBC URL was missing the "jdbc:" part. The rest of the environment variables were fine. Thank you!